# How to use Lookup in Sharepoint 2013 to populate another list with all tasks from multiple lists

Tags: 2013

Morning folks,

I'm using SP 2013. I have ten lists, all for different geographic areas. They all have the same columns and hold the same kind of data.

Because of the changes to SP I cannot search all the lists in one go, I need to be in the list and search that list, then change to the next list, search that list, etc.

I also have staff who have get assigned tasks from multiple lists and have to manage those tasks, but again they have to go in to each list to get their tasks.

Is there a way I can:

1. Merge all tasks from all lists into one new super list that would run alongside the others?
2. Have a list for each staff member that would pull all their tasks from the other lists into that staff list?

I don't have access to Workflow, Designer or anything else. It's only what can be done via the standard SP interface.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guess you need developed this case ot looking for by market solutions with the same functionality such us: BoostSolution, Virto Software. Those vendors have products with this functionality. If you select developed You will need dynamically generate and orchestrate all items in a dynamically SPList it is not trivious.